# How should I start setting up a javascript that gathers information and shows it in an generated html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify, require, jenkins-api

This is my first javascript project and I am aware that I just don't know some pretty basic things.

I want to build a html file with javascript that shows the status of some jenkins jobs

What would be a way to start this project. 
Currently I am trying to install the required modules (jenkins-api, require, jQuery, jsdom, browserify) via npm install xyz and than build via browserify the javascript-file.

But this isn't really working properly...

How would somebody begin a task like that?

Comment: What isn't working as you expect?

Comment: Maybe reading this helps you improving the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the jenkins-api module doesn´t seem to work with browserify...
function calls that work with the node correctly return "undefined" in the browser.
should browserify work with every library?